# Creating DMF error by Wizard

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, wizard, x++

I'm creating a DMF to populate the AX Standard Table **SmmSalesUnit**.

But when I launch the standard AX Wizard to create a DMF Iget an error *To a foreign key constraint it is only possible to add a constraint related to fixed field*
I have this standard relation [image: smmSalesUnitRelation] and this [image: Error]

How can I by-pass the problem?

Thanks,

Enjoy.

Comment: I can reproduce the issue on a AX 2012 R3 CU 11 system, but did not have the chance to investigate further. You could always create the entity manually instead of using the wizard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug in the data import/export framework. As a workaround you can comment the following line in method `generate` of class `DMFGenerateEntityTable` and uncomment it after generation
[image]